# Use PHP to connect to FTP and backup all folder contents

Tags: php, backup

I'm building a custom web app that stores the FTP and MySQL settings for the websites I manage for clients. My goal is not only to store the settings for reference, but to create functionality to assist in doing regular backups.

I've got the MySQL backup functionality working great, as it connects to the remote databases, creates a dump and sends it to my browser to download locally.

BUT... what is the best way to connect to a remote FTP and download all the contents of a specific folder to my local computer?

Any suggestions would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

This example from the php manual posted by mroerick might help you.

```
    <?php 
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com"; 
$conn_id = ftp_connect ($ftp_server) 
    or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server"); 

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "user", "pass"); 
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) 
    die("FTP Connection Failed"); 

ftp_sync (".");

ftp_close($conn_id);  

function ftp_sync ($dir) { 

    global $conn_id; 

    if ($dir != ".") { 
        if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, $dir) == false) { 
            echo ("Change Dir Failed: $dir<BR>\r\n"); 
            return; 
        } 
        if (!(is_dir($dir))) 
            mkdir($dir); 
        chdir ($dir); 
    } 

    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "."); 
    foreach ($contents as $file) { 

        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') 
            continue; 

        if (@ftp_chdir($conn_id, $file)) { 
            ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
            ftp_sync ($file); 
        } 
        else 
            ftp_get($conn_id, $file, $file, FTP_BINARY); 
    } 

    ftp_chdir ($conn_id, ".."); 
    chdir (".."); 

} 
?>
```